# php unset key in array makes script fail

Tags: php, arrays, key, unset

I am having an issue whan calling unset on an array's key, here is the non-working code

```
 $updatedcontact = $_POST;

 unset($updatedcontact['_id'];
```

I know that the _id key exists (even if it would not my script should still work I guess) because when I comment the unset line and var_dump the array I get this:

```
 array (size=9)
 '_id' => string '50e1aff66d2a0fcf48000000' (length=24)
```

When the unset line is not commented I simply get a blank page

I read the php manual and searched but it damn looks like I do it right to my eyes (and it works in a test script I wrote), hope someone will find my begginer's mistake.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Blank page mainly means your errors aren't printed, look in the log files for the exact issue.

Comment: Always develop with `display_errors` on.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  A blank page usually means a fatal error.

Comment: I had error reporting on, just look under and you'll see that it was predictable that my script wouldn't interprete correctly, I don't know how I've been able to miss a missing parenthesis for one hour or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax Error, Closing ) Missing

```
unset($updatedcontact['_id'];
```

Should be

```
unset($updatedcontact['_id']);
```

Comment: Lol ok xD sorry for such a dumb question!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `unset()` parenthesis

```
$updatedcontact = $_POST;

unset($updatedcontact['_id']);
                          --^--
```

Comment: Oops sorry Mr. Alien, i didnt know you were posting at the same time or i would not submit a double answer

Comment: @HankyPanky it's ok, you can just keep your answer too, as many questions have duplicate answers :) just a matter of timing